# what tools can be used to perform automation and performance testing

Tags: automation

We have a SFDC application and as a functional tester I would like to know what tools can be used to automate the test scripts. Need to test UI as well as the functional requirements of application. Can I use QTP, selenium to achieve this. Or is there better tool given by SFDC?

Answer (score 4):

For automating testing and builds in general, I would try Jenkins:
http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2013/03/setting-up-jenkins-for-force-com-continuous-integration.html

Which has a Selenium plugin too:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin

tbh, discussions around automated UI testing always seem to gravitate around Selenium.  There are other options, but it is a good place to start.

For fine tuning (not auto) UI perfomance, I would look at using either Chrome or FireFox's built in development tools as well as the View State inspector in Visualforce:
http://developer.force.com/releases/release/Winter11/View+State+Inspector

Comment: Autotuning is not fine, you mean?

Answer (score 3):

Selenium is a good choice if you are planning concurrent testing.

http://www.slideshare.net/developerforce/df121279-patterson-randy-changes

This is an excellent slide to refer.Load runner can be used for load testing.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_JMeter

Jmeter is a free tool that can be used for testing .You may also engage salesforce for performance testing.Fiddler is another excellent tool

Comment: I'd be careful about using something like JMeter directly on Salesforce to load test.  SF does their own loading testing and [states that it is unnecessary](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dev_lifecycle/Content/test.htm).  Like you said, it would be a good idea to contact them first.  Don't want to get into trouble, multi-tenant environment, etc.

Comment: Completely agree that involving salesforce in load testing is a better approach

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I work for Provar, a Salesforce test automation product (www.provartesting.com). I will give an honest answer but of course I am biased :)

I worked for a Salesforce consultancy for many years implementing Salesforce projects. Salesforce doesn't have any native options for test automation (this was why Provar was created in the first place). So your options are:

1. use something like Selenium, QTP and build it yourself
2. use a specialised 3rd party product.

There are big overheads to writing and maintaining your own framework. In general we recommend against writing code when implementing Salesforce itself, because it is more time-consuming and difficult to maintain than configuration. But granted there are also overheads to 3rd party products. consider what is the best strategy for your business, but be prepared for some kind of overhead either way.

In my opinion a good Salesforce test automation solution should be the following:

1. does not require code to use
2. allows you to run test cases across different environments and browsers without requiring changes to the test case
3. can handle minor cosmetic changes without tests breaking (e.g. moving fields on a page layout or Visualforce page)
4. can test advanced elements like Visualforce and Service Cloud console (even if you don't use these elements now: you may want to in future, and it's a good test for product capability)
5. can be connected to other systems such as databases and email integrations, as this will help you to do true end-to-end testing instead of just Salesforce
6. can generate reports automatically
7. is Lightning compatible (Lightning is the new Salesforce UI - if your business is considering a future move to this UI, invest in a product that will allow you to run tests in both UIs)

Our tool, Provar, does all of these. But actually I recommend you avoid taking product recommendations from individuals on this thread as you will be bombarded with marketing messages :) so take a look at the suggestions, but also do your own googling for 'salesforce test automation' and compare the tools yourself depending on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps AssureClick (AppExchange) is what you are looking for: functional tests, deployment and security testing. No coding required.
Generates Apex test code which can be leveraged in the code.
See www.ext-it.com
Not a free app, though.

Comment: Do you work for them by chance? If so you edit your answer to disclose that.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for staging and configuring your existing Salesforce data Test Data Architect (TDA).  You can extract the SF data objects/columns of your choice and then configure the tests you need based on data attributes. It would pair very well with any UI solution out there like Selenium to serve as a reusable data foundation.

http://www.testdatarchitects.com/

Answer (score 0):

Please check out ATTEST for your UAT/BAT and Integration Testing needs. It is available in AppExchange with a free trial. ATTEST helps you to easily test not only your Salesforce Applications but also other applications in your enterprise including Oracle Applications, SAP, Workday etc.

Disclosure: I am CEO and Co-founder at Entegration Software

Answer (score 0):

Check out ITAS for Salesforce. It is totally scriptless plug and play solution for functional test case automation, performance and regression testing. It has cloud based version and in minutes can scale up and down load. Literally automate Salesforce testing in hours! ITAS is already on Salesforce AppExchange.

http://fusionsystemsinc.com/salesforce/

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000DpSm7EAF